# How can I have a class variable along with Bootstrap classes on my button?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, debugging, jsx

I have a variable which's based on a ternary (they're CSS classes I defined for colors):

```
let color_switch_size = this.state.white ? "white-btn" : "green-btn";
```

I have a button:

```
<button className={`${color_switch_size} text-capitalize font-weight-bold mt-3 mb-0 btn btn-light`} onClick={this.sizeClicked}>{small}</button>
```

**A**. When clicking the button without the Bootstrap classes and only `color_switch_size` populated in `className`, the button toggles colors without any problems.

**B**. However, when I try to populate `color_switch_size` in `className` along with the Bootstrap classes, the toggling doesn't work anymore.

How'd I get my toggling to work along with the Bootstrap classes in place?  What am I doing wrong?

I tried:

```
let color_switch_size = this.state.white ? "white-btn text-capitalize font-weight-bold mt-3 mb-0 btn btn-light" : "green-btn text-capitalize font-weight-bold mt-3 mb-0 btn btn-light";
```

But it's giving me the same result as **B**

Comment: does the bootstrap work without the color toggle?

Comment: @bowl_of_rice yeah it does

Comment: What does the button setup look like after you update ```color_switch_size```
to include the bootstrap?

Comment: @bowl_of_rice Here's a pastebin of my code, it might answer most of your questions.  I'm just so stumped :( https://pastebin.com/vvUWUhh6

Comment: Is there anything else I can do to help you find an answer to your question @testman?

Answer (score 0):

Without any CSS provided its a little bit difficult to tell 100%, but I assume that both `white-btn` and `green-btn` sets `background: #somecolor`. In the classlist you have provided you also add a bootstrap-class of `btn-light` which also sets background-color for your button and porobably overwrites your background-color.

Ether:

- Remove `btn-light` from the classlist
- Change your CSS for `white-btn` and `green-btn` so they have [higher specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than `btn-light`
- Rearrange your classlist so that `btn-light` is before `color_switch_size` *(Which may or may not work depending on your CSS specificity)*

```
<button className={`btn-light ${color_switch_size} text-capitalize font-weight-bold mt-3 mb-0 btn`} onClick={this.sizeClicked}>{small}</button>
```